# How can I return a boolean when a variable contains any one of the elements of my vector?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I have a vector:

```
v <- c("apple","banana","orange")
```

I want to search a column in my dataset and return either `TRUE` or `FALSE` if **any** of the elements of `v` are present.

As an example:

```
mystring <- "I have a grape but I have nothing else except an apple"
```

The solution I came up with is to use `str_count` to count the number of times my vector elements appear in `mystring` and then `mutate` based on the counts to get my boolean values -- ie, using `case_when` count > 0 and count == 0).

This seems like a poor approach. I'd really appreciate some guidance on a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can paste the elements in 'v' to a single string and use `str_detect`

```
library(stringr)
str_detect(mystring, str_c("\\b(", str_c(v, collapse="|"), ")\\b"))
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

We could create a pattern then use `grepl`:

```
pattern <- paste(v, collapse = "|")
grepl(pattern, mystring)

[1] TRUE
```